# Multiple request params with Locale 'lang' param

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization

I'm developing SpringBoot application. I have several locale languages and when I change them on thymleaf pages which require their own request params, I get an exception like:

```
Required request parameter 'projectId' for method parameter type int is not present]
```

The link I used to change locale is:

```
<a  th:href="@{?lang=fr}" > <button type="button" class="btn h-lang " >fr</button></a>
<a  th:href="@{?lang=du}" ><button type="button" class="btn h-lang">nl</button></a>
```

When I click the link, it overrides request parameters in current URL with it's own.

```
http://localhost:8080/projects/project_details?lang=fr
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:8080/projects/project_details?projectId=12
```

the method :

```
public String project_details(@RequestParam("projectId") int theId, Model theModel){
```

I searched a lot on internet but I did not find anything can help me , I changed RequestParam to pathvariable and pathparam but it didnt work !

Comment: I don't understand, in thymleaf you pass lang, and in the controller, you wait for projectId!!

Comment: how can i pass language and project id in controlller ?!

Comment: You mean `@RequestParam("lang") String lang, @RequestParam("projectId") int theId`

Comment: why  i can change the language in the homepage that doesnt need a reuquestparam !

Comment: the problem is just that i got error when there is requestparam !

Comment: I think maybe the problem with thymleaf ! how can i make it to accept control:ers with multiparam  @you

Comment: Check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-request-parameters